# How to start a gnome-terminal with command from the systemd service on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-20.04, systemd-service

I wrote e service file called */etc/systemd/system/mytest.service* . Then I would like to start a new terminal window with some commands that print on the new terminal console.

The file mytest.service has this content:

```
[Unit]
Description= Test
After= network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -- "echo 'test' > /home/me/test.log; echo 'abcd';"

StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

After running `sudo systemctl start mytest` and print the status I got this error messages:

```
Sep 23 21:09:50 ub20 gnome-terminal[4205]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Sep 23 21:09:50 ub20 gnome-terminal[4205]: # Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
Sep 23 21:09:50 ub20 systemd[1]: ethminer.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a systemd user folder in `$HOME/.config/systemd/user
2. Create or copy the service file to the folder, e.g: *mytest.service*
3. Run `systemctl --user enable mytest.service`